# Product Page Help

Tags: products, coding

I am looking at having my product page normal again.  After a recent update, our products seemed to go 4 in one row then 1 in the next.  http://hollandbarstool.com/product-categories/metal-series-30.html

Please Help and thanks!

Comment: Wich Magento version ? and what you want to to exaclty?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the below css in http://hollandbarstool.com/skin/frontend/fortis/default/css/_config/layout_default.css

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1280px)
layout_default.css:73
.itemgrid-adaptive.itemgrid-4col .item:nth-child(5n+1) {
    /* clear: left !important; */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- For screen greater than 1280px

Remove below commented line from css in http://hollandbarstool.com/skin/frontend/fortis/default/css/_config/layout_default.css

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1280px)
layout_default.css:73
.itemgrid-adaptive.itemgrid-4col .item:nth-child(5n+1) {
    /* clear: left !important; */
}
```

- For screen between 767px to 1280px

Remove below commented line from css in http://hollandbarstool.com/skin/frontend/fortis/default/css/infortis/_shared/itemgrid.css

```
.itemgrid-4col .item:nth-child(4n+1) {
    /* clear: left; */
}
```

Hope you have issue on those two screen sizes only.